# jquery accessing dynamic class selectors

Tags: jquery

Given the following html rendering;

```
<fieldset id="fld_Rye">
 <legend>7 Main St.</legend>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <th class="wideCol"><b><i>Service Description</i></b></th>
        <th class="wideCol"><b><i>Service Name</i></b></th>
        <th class="normalPlusWidth"><b><i>Contact Name</i></b></th>        
    </tr>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="">
        <td class="servDesc">&nbsp;<b>Plumbing Services</b></td>
                    <td class="servName">&nbsp;<b>Flynnsters's Plumbing</b></td>
                    <td class="servContact">&nbsp;<b>Jim Flynnster</b></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

I am trying to access all the td's with a class of servDesc, get their width into an array and get the max width from that array to reset the css width of that class using jquery on page load. I cant seem to get the right selector for those tags, and I've tried at least 50 variations.

My latest try;

```
 var maxTdWidth;
        var servDescCols = [];
        $("#fld_Rye td#servDesc").each(function () {
            alert("found one");
            servDescCols.push($(this).width());
        });
        maxTdWidth = Math.max.apply(Math, servDescCols);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get all the `td` with `servDesc` class try this

```
$("td.servDesc").each(function () {
            alert("found one");
            servDescCols.push(this.width());
     });
```

if you want to target any element and get the td inside use this

'table1' is the id of the base element

```
$("#table1").find("td.servDesc").each(function () {
        alert("found one");
        servDescCols.push(this.width());
 });
```

Comment: yes, I know that works but this page may have more than the one table and I wanted a little more hierarchy in the selector, ie defining the div and the sub td.servDesc versus just any td.servDesc tag, it also only finds one when their are multiple on the page

Comment: That does work, but there are 17 td tags with that selector and its only finding one, or better yet, the push function isnt working and the script is exiting after the first go around. I also changed this to $(this)